# HTML - How to run a file from the user pc?

Tags: html, file, local

I'm creating a little project in HTML and there's something that I would like to do.
Imagine that my HTML page is hosted, and you can download there some .ppt and .exe files and place to a specific folder.
Now, that's the problem. Considering that the files are in the right folder, I would like to run these files when the user select their respective options at the HTML page.
Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly possible, for security reasons.

If you control that application or can install something on the user's system, you can associate a file type or URI handler with the application you wish to launch.

Comment: Yes, I could ask the users to install something. Could give me a light of how could I associate a file with the application?
Thanks a lot o/

Comment: @RamonMachado That depends on the OS.  On Windows, check out...   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx